# Issue with preg_match() function

Tags: php, regex

I want to run the following `regex` in `PHP` but I faced with the error that says:

> **preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'**

My Code:

```
if (preg_match("^(?!.*(l_name|f_name|m_name)).*$", $str)) {
   // Do sth 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add delimiteeeeeeeeeeeeeers ! For example `#` at the begin and the end :p

Comment: @HamZa Added and error has been gone but the regex doesn't work, however it is work on JAVA!

Comment: @iSun To figure out why your regex doesn't work we need your `$str`, or else we haven't got a clue what's in the string.

Comment: [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx) library can automatically add delimiters, so author's code would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if (preg_match("/^(?!.*(l_name|f_name|m_name)).*$/", $str)) {
   // Do sth    ^                                ^
}
```